# How do I store and retrieve connection strings from my web.config file in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

How to store and retrieve connection string from web.config file in ASP.Net ?

Comment: at least try google yourslef...

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Configuration;

ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["some Key"].ToString();
```